# Scala Implementation of Reflection to find Member Name

Tags: scala, reflection

If I have a case class situation like this:

```
case class ColorId(id: Int)
```

With a companion object that looks like this:

```
/**
  * Contains all possible colors that can be applied.
  */
object ColorId {
  val RED = ColorId(1)
  val GREEN = ColorId(2)
  val BLUE = ColorId(3)
  val WHITE = ColorId(4)
  val BLACK = ColorId(5)
  val UNKNOWN = ColorId(6)
}

val blue = ColorId.BLUE

assert(blue.getNameString == "BLUE")
```

There is surely a way to use reflection to get the assert to be true.
How should the implementation of the `ColorId` object's `getNameString` method look?

EDIT: There does not need to be a specific method. For example something like `blue.getClass.getXXX.getName` is acceptable.

EDIT #2: Removing this comparable part.

Comment: Are you sure you want `Comparable`? I would suggest you using [`Ordering`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html). Second, every time you think about **reflection** in Scala, there is a better way. Please consider using [**Enumeratum**](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) for defining this.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - This is what I have to work with already as this example is a simplification of current code used in production. We've had problems with Enums in Spark. You can ignore the comparable part.

Comment: What about a simple **Map[Int, String]** so that you can get the name given the code? Or you need the specific name assigned to the `val`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Maps are bad practice for schemas as the cause some issues. (I don't recall the exact issue - something like comparing or sorting - it's been a while since I've seen that error.)  Note: This field is going into an avro file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
case class ColorId(id: Int)

object ColorId {
  val RED = ColorId(1)
  val GREEN = ColorId(2)
  val BLUE = ColorId(3)
  val WHITE = ColorId(4)
  val BLACK = ColorId(5)
  val UNKNOWN = ColorId(6)
}

object UnsafeColorIdMap {
  lazy val nameById: Map[Int, String] = {
    scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
      .classSymbol(ColorId.getClass)
      .info
      .members
      .filter(_.isMethod)
      .map(_.name.toString)
      .filter(_.forall(Character.isUpperCase))
      .toList
      .reverse
      .zip(LazyList from 1)
      .toMap
      .map(_.swap)
  }
}

final implicit class UnsafeColorToNameString(private val c: ColorId) extends AnyVal {
  def unsafeGetNameString: String = UnsafeColorIdMap.nameById(c.id)
}

assert(ColorId.BLUE.unsafeGetNameString == "BLUE")
```

however note the **unsafe** prefix.

Comment: I get an error: not found: value LazyList
            .zip(LazyList from 1)
                  --- This seems like it's what I'm looking for tho

Comment: @codeaperature Try `Stream from 1` instead of `LazyList from 1` .

Answer (score 1):

What I was suggesting was using a simple **Map** to get the name of color given its `id`.

Something like this:

```
object ColorId {
  val RED = ColorId(1)
  val GREEN = ColorId(2)
  val BLUE = ColorId(3)
  val WHITE = ColorId(4)
  val BLACK = ColorId(5)
  val UNKNOWN = ColorId(6)

  def getName(color: ColorId): String = color.id match {
    case 1 => "RED"
    case 2 => "GREEN"
    case 3 => "BLUE"
    case 4 => "WHITE"
    case 5 => "BLACK"
    case 6 => "UNKNOWN"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... This is one of the options I considered, but is seems this duplicates code and does not use reflection.

Comment: @codeaperature why do you insist on using a bad practice like **reflection**? Second, yes this will duplicate the code, I proposed a solution that didn't duplicate the code using **Eumeratum** _(not an enum)_ but you discarded it. Finally, not even reflection would work here, since you want the name of the variable, not a field of a class.

Comment: @ LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - I'm not trying to make it hard for you. I have a code base that uses this practice (for better or worse) and therefore I'm looking to find a simple way to work with this object (which is imported into another code base) ... If I can simply reflect this variable name, it's even better because I can easily make a minor change to second code base where this reflection is needed. (And sorry I incorrectly used Enum as an abbreviation earlier.)

Comment: @codeaperature What exactly do you need? I do not understand. Do you want to get the string `BLUE` for any instance of `ColorId` whose `id` is `3`? Or do you want to the `BLUE` instance from a String with the value `BLUE`, or do you want to the name of the variable on which you are calling the method?

Comment: In this case, I want the string `"BLUE"` which should be accessed from `3` or `ColorId(3)` or the value `blue`. If I can access without changing the object definition, that's a huge plus.

Comment: So you do need something like what I proposed. You may use reflection or macros or a simple code generation script to avoid the manual boilerplate, but you would need to create a method like this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206541/discussion-between-codeaperature-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).